Why is this alarm in alarm state?
There are clearly at least 1 period where the condition was non breaching out of 24. But somehow for that one hour its not alarming and then it is again.
My understanding is that saying 24 of 24 (1 hour) periods means all 24 of the past hours must be breaching, if even 1 is not then the alarm is OK.  This is how I check for the thing ran at least 1 time per day. Technically 3 times but that's the threshold < 3. All 3 run at the same time, and only take a couple minutes.

I have other alarms setup this way that operate fine.
I'm testing for the presence of a data point >=3 within an hour, once every 24 hours. Otherwise alarm.
